# Element with Overflow:auto affected by Floating Element

Tags: html, css, overflow

Can someone explain to me why overflow has the following effect.

In the jsfiddle below I have a Div floated to the left with a width and height set.
Next I have a Content div. You could think about this as a left navigation and a content of a site layout.

Inside the content I have two Divs which are identical apart from one has overflow:auto the other doesn't. The one with overflow:auto currently respects the floated div and shortens its width to not clash with it. Were as the other one simply keeps its full width and runs underneth the floated div.

Although the overflow:auto gives a very userful behaviour I do not understand why it cares about the floated item. I thought if a element has a certain width and the content inside that cannot fit, then it will do your requested behaviour but this is sort of applying the behaviour to the element itself

http://jsfiddle.net/9bEDj/1/

Can someone clarify this for me and explain why this is the behaviour or if it shouldn't actually be doing this and its a quirk!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a fabulous description on the float/overflow magic
http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

It's the intended behaviour that elements with overflow other than visible should respect the floats, so you can use it with not causing any fuzz

Comment: again a great article and for its simplicity I am marking this as the answer!

Answer (score 5):

It happens because [setting `overflow` establishes a new block formatting context, and block formatting contexts do not overlap floats](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/).

Comment: was a great read and really has opened my eyes to more overflow users