# Relative Positioning pushes Link Text down

Tags: html, hyperlink, css-position, css

I'll let this jsfiddle describe most of the problem for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/zAPVQ/4/

I've got a layout similar to this. There's an image to the left and block links to the right. The way I've set the positioning, the text inside the `<a>` is pushed down underneath the blocks.

I've created a makeshift solution, using `<span>` tags and more positioning, but I'd rather that not be my end result. If I have to create/change/remove buttons, I'd have to mess with the positioning of the text.

Does anyone know a better way of keeping the text inside the link block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAPVQ/5/).

I've added

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to your big link CSS.

Saw this today from another answer to this question [Element with Overflow:auto affected by Floating Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807828/element-with-overflowauto-affected-by-floating-element)

Theres also a couple of good links to a description of why it works in there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a negative margin. Like margin-top: -75px;